# Landsat 8 images acquisition_date

Tags: image, landsat, date

I need to know the exact date of image acquisition for NDVI purpose, the date on image name is " LC8092085**2014222**LGN00" is in Julian date, but in meta data it says"acquisition_date>2014-08-10" , I assume that I can use the date in meta data, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the acquisition_date in the metadata, which is the date in ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD).

The date in the filename is Year+Julian Day.

You can check the acquisition date against the filename if you wish using the [NASA Julian Day Calendar](http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/browse/calendar.html)

This shows 2014-08-10 = 2014222